# how would a flightless bat's feet/ hands evolve?

Tags: biology, evolution

plantigrade? digitigrade? unguligrade? the bat would be large, anywhere from wolf to horse sized. i'm thinking the back feet make sense to be digitigrade, but i'm not sure what the devolution of a bat wing to hand would result in.

Comment: It would depend in the time and necesity really, remember that most mamals descent from a mouse like survivor from dinosaur apocalypse.

Comment: How did they become flightless, what type of niche are they filling?

Comment: dThis question is unclear since we do not have enough information about this bat to hypothesize on how it might evolve? Does it still have wings? If not I wouldn't think it's a bat. But what does it do with wings then? Does it swim?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Dibran*! I agree with previous comments that the question in its current form is quite unclear and missing some necessary information. It would be nice if you could [edit] it, otherwise your question might get put on hold until you [edit]ed it. Furthermore it would be nice if you could have a look at your capitalization to make it easier to read the question. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: This is a fine speculative biology question.  It is actually very narrowly focused for this type of question:  how, specifically (and specific foot types are offered) would the feet of a flightless bat look?  Reopen.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the biological niche it's trying to fill. The obvious need for a loss of flight is that it simply became too large to sustain flight anymore, which means it needs to do something else *better than its competition* to survive. Some examples in [this article](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/tetrapod-zoology/giant-flightless-bats-from-the-future/).

Bats, modern day, have hands that double as wings, and that needs to be taken into account for **ground-based quadrupedal** locomotion. As the vestigial wings start to disappear, the neo-bat will need to walk on its knuckles to avoid breaking its own fingers, and likely adopt a somewhat ape-like appearance. Moving forward in time is where things start getting complicated. In the ever-present need to out-compete other creatures, the neo-bat starts to develop a more specialized appearance.  If they need speed the neo-bat will likely grow into a more lean, evenly balanced frame, driving divergence from their knuckle-walk, likely resulting in fused fingers, shorter finger-bones, and/or otherwise rotated hand structure to better absorb impacts and improve maneuverability and reach. Strength-based evolution would likely result in evolution similar to a gorilla in appearance, as well as a possible likelihood toward ambush predation. **alternative means of locomotion** would be cause for different structures, neo-bats that jump up cliff-sides would likely retain the semi-delicate graspers of either the fore or hind limbs and the opposing set would likely be dedicated towards propelling themselves. Purely climbing based neo-bats would likely retain similar hand/foot structure, with varying limb structure based on environmental need, as well as inclination towards feeding behavior. Swimmers are the most likely to retain wing-structures long-term, with climbing-based in no particular hurry to get rid of them, given a slight gliding advantage, while purely ground-based neo-bats are hampered by vestigial wings impeding locomotion.

Answer (score 1):

**Take some cues from a bat that is the most flightless of any.**

The Lesser Short Tailed Bat is unique to New Zealand.  They can still fly but like flightless New Zealand birds, these bats have traded some of their aerial prowess to take over the terrestrial ecosystem dominated everywhere else by rodents.  Look how fast they scuttle over the ground!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2wjXRTd1vU

As a contrast here is an unfortunate more normal type of bat trying to make its way across the ground.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZC-qYDNVvc

The partly terrestrial (and burrowing!) Mystacina have strong, ratlike back legs.  They can fold their wings all the way up into little sticks to get the floppy webs out of the way.  The winglike structure between their back legs rolls up too.

https://www.teara.govt.nz/en/bats/page-2

> Once they arrived in New Zealand, lesser short-tailed bats continued
>   to evolve. They developed characteristics not found anywhere else in
>   the world and have become a biological oddity. They are the only bat
>   species that forages for food on the ground, like small rodents.
>   Several adaptations make this possible: their robust hind legs have
>   small claws, and their wings fold down completely and can be tucked
>   away under side flaps of thicker skin. This allows the bat to use the
>   elbow part of the wings as front legs.

from [M. J. DANIEL The New Zealand short-tailed bat, Mystacina tuberculata;a review of present knowledge. Neww Zealand Journal of Zoology, 1979, Vol. 6, 357-370](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03014223.1979.10428375)
[image: lesser short tailed bat, wings furled for ground travel]

Another cool thing is this "basal talon".  Two claws on each digit.  I have never seen anything like that.  I have no clue why that is helpful to the bat and why, if it is somehow good for landgoing critters of this size, we do not see it in anything else.  If someone knows please say or link in comments.

[Mammalogy: Adaptation, Diversity, Ecology By George A. Feldhamer](https://books.google.com/books?id=udCnKce9hfoC&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=%22basal+talon%22+mystacina&source=bl&ots=vN2nqVUSTd&sig=-LQYjNeGq25moWAUj5sy__FeHV8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEl7m_pZ7WAhXDTSYKHQ-xC8MQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%22basal%20talon%22%20mystacina&f=false)
[image: basal talon of lesser short tailed bat]

[image: Mystcina drawing]
from http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Mystacina_tuberculata/
Note the elbow of the bat with the "thumb" on it. Nice drawing Francesca Ivaldi!

So for your flightless bat

1:  Wings furl to sticks
2: Just one weight bearing finger on top of "forelimb".  Make it strong!
3: "Basal talons" of course.  Especially on that strong finger.
4: Bats have flying in their soul.  In New Zealand even the birds gave up flight.  But bats could not.  Bats gotta fly.  Even your mongo Moa bat should be able to glide a little way.